# MAVROS does not work with ARNI

Tags: roslaunch, roscore, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use arni tool in order to monitor some topics published by gazebo simulation. My simulation scenario requires running MAVROS to control UAV in simulation but Whenever I run the simulation first then the arni tool, the arni gets shut down. Also, when i run arni first and then the simulator, the MAVROS shuts down. I am not sure why both arni and MAVROS can't run at same time.

The arni command I'm using only initializes parameters, it doesn't even run a node. The command is as follows:

$ roslaunch arni_core init_params.launch   ( this command from ros arni tutorials)

Note: I used arni to monitor other topics and it worked fine so basically the problem is when running MAVROS and arni.
Also, another weird problem faced is that arni doesn't work with roscore, it shuts down when the roscore is running.

Could you help me in finding a solution, and understanding why this problem happens ??

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241229/mavros-does-not-work-with-arni/) by [Alaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27700/alaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, sorry to reply so late, I just recently discovered your question. Hope I can still help you but I need a little more information to be able to do that.
What kind of versions of ROS are you using? And are you using the same version on all hosts?
Any visible exceptions on the console?
Can you post some output from ROS, a good start would be

- "rostopic list" before the start of mavlink and before and after starting ARNI
- "rosparam get /"  before and after starting ARNI
- roswtf before and after starting ARNI
- rqt_graph before  and after starting ARNI

Thanks for using ARNI, we're always eager to hear from anybody using it.

---

Originally posted by [Matthias Hadlich](https://answers.ros.org/users/24950/matthias-hadlich/) with karma: 70 on 2016-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0